# Different top-level domain redirection RSpec/Capybara test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a rather general question regarding RSpec/Capybara. If an application does a redirection based on the TLD (for example, both example.com and example.net resolve to the same IP but the request to the first one gets redirected to example.com/locale_com and the request to the second one - to example.net/locale_net), how would the request tests look like? The app is written in Rails.

I can think of one way to do it - add entries for both hosts (example.com and example.net) to resolve to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts - but that won't work for me, since tests would be run on different machines with no root access.

Comment: I have the same problem.I want test SSO redirection in rspec. when I write `visit '/users/sign_in'` it point to another domain. but in test case, it receive the request again. really weird.

Answer (score 0):

I would test this within my Rspec controller tests:

```
describe MyController do
  describe "GET index" do
    before(:each) do
      request.host = "example.net"
      get :index
    end

    it "should redirect .net to .com" do
      uri = URI.parse(response.headers["Location"])
      expect(uri.host).to eq "example.com"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the redirection occurs via the routes file, you can test this outside the controller spec using this code:

```
describe "Route Redirects" do
  describe "GET example.net" do
    before(:each) do
      request.host = "example.net"
      get "/"
    end

    it "redirect to example.com" do
      expect(response.code).to eq 302
      uri = URI.parse(response.location)
      expect(uri.host).to eq "example.com"
    end
  end
end
```